# Reading .dat file into R

Tags: r, pca, read.table, psych

I have a .dat file that I need to import into R. I have tried using read.table and read.delim funtions. It did not work

Heres how the .dat file looks. the name of the file is US Judge Ratings.dat

```
USJudgeRatings <-
data.frame(CONT = c(5.7, 6.8, 7.2, 6.8, 7.3, 6.2, 10.6, 7, 7.3, 8.2,
7, 6.5, 6.7, 7, 6.5, 7.3, 8, 7.7, 8.3, 9.6, 7.1, 7.6, 6.6, 6.2, 7.5, 7.8,
7.1, 7.5, 7.5, 7.1, 6.6, 8.4, 6.9, 7.3, 7.7, 8.5, 6.9, 6.5, 8.3, 8.3, 9,
7.1, 8.6), INTG = c(7.9, 8.9, 8.1, 8.8, 6.4, 8.8, 9, 5.9, 8.9, 7.9, 8,
8, 8.6, 7.5, 8.1, 8, 7.6, 7.7, 8.2, 6.9, 8.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.3, 8.7, 8.9,
8.5, 9, 8.1, 9.2, 7.4, 8, 8.5, 8.9, 6.2, 8.3, 8.3, 8.2, 7.3, 8.2, 7, 8.4,
7.4), DMNR = c(7.7, 8.8, 7.8, 8.5, 4.3, 8.7, 8.9, 4.9, 8.9, 6.7, 7.6, 7.6,
8.2, 6.4, 8, 7.4, 6.6, 6.7, 7.4, 5.7, 7.7, 6.9, 6.2, 8.1, 8.5, 8.7, 8.3,
8.9, 7.7, 9, 6.9, 7.9, 7.8, 8.8, 5.1, 8.1, 8, 7.7, 7, 7.8, 5.9, 8.4, 7),
DILG = c(7.3, 8.5, 7.8, 8.8, 6.5, 8.5, 8.7, 5.1, 8.7, 8.1, 7.4, 7.2, 6.8,
6.8, 8, 7.7, 7.2, 7.5, 7.8, 6.6, 7.1, 6.8, 6.2, 7.7, 8.6, 8.9, 8, 8.7,
8.2, 9, 8.4, 7.9, 8.5, 8.7, 5.6, 8.3, 8.1, 7.8, 6.8, 8.3, 7, 7.7, 7.5),
CFMG = c(7.1, 7.8, 7.5, 8.3, 6, 7.9, 8.5, 5.4, 8.6, 7.9, 7.3, 7,
6.9, 6.5, 7.9, 7.3, 6.5, 7.4, 7.7, 6.9, 6.6, 6.7, 5.4, 7.4, 8.5,
8.7, 7.9, 8.4, 8, 8.4, 8, 7.8, 8.1, 8.4, 5.6, 8.4, 7.9, 7.6, 7,
8.4, 7, 7.5, 7.5), DECI = c(7.4, 8.1, 7.6, 8.5, 6.2, 8, 8.5, 5.9,
8.5, 8, 7.5, 7.1, 6.6, 7, 8, 7.3, 6.5, 7.5, 7.7, 6.6, 6.6, 6.8,
5.7, 7.3, 8.4, 8.8, 7.9, 8.5, 8.1, 8.6, 7.9, 7.8, 8.2, 8.5, 5.9,
8.2, 7.9, 7.7, 7.1, 8.3, 7.2, 7.7, 7.7), PREP = c(7.1, 8, 7.5, 8.7,
5.7, 8.1, 8.5, 4.8, 8.4, 7.9, 7.1, 6.9, 7.1, 6.6, 7.9, 7.3, 6.8,
7.1, 7.7, 6.2, 6.7, 6.4, 5.8, 7.3, 8.5, 8.9, 7.8, 8.4, 8.2, 9.1,
8.2, 7.6, 8.4, 8.5, 5.6, 8.2, 7.9, 7.7, 6.7, 7.7, 6.9, 7.8, 7.4),
FAMI = c(7.1, 8, 7.5, 8.7, 5.7, 8, 8.5, 5.1, 8.4, 8.1, 7.2, 7, 7.3,
6.8, 7.8, 7.2, 6.7, 7.3, 7.8, 6, 6.7, 6.3, 5.9, 7.3, 8.5, 9, 7.8,
8.3, 8.4, 9.1, 8.4, 7.4, 8.5, 8.5, 5.6, 8.1, 7.7, 7.7, 6.7, 7.6,
6.9, 8.2, 7.2), ORAL = c(7.1, 7.8, 7.3, 8.4, 5.1, 8, 8.6, 4.7, 8.4,
7.7, 7.1, 7, 7.2, 6.3, 7.8, 7.1, 6.4, 7.1, 7.5, 5.8, 6.8, 6.3, 5.2,
7.2, 8.4, 8.8, 7.8, 8.3, 8, 8.9, 7.7, 7.4, 8.1, 8.4, 5.3, 7.9, 7.6,
7.5, 6.7, 7.5, 6.5, 8, 6.9), WRIT = c(7, 7.9, 7.4, 8.5, 5.3, 8,
8.4, 4.9, 8.5, 7.8, 7.2, 7.1, 7.2, 6.6, 7.8, 7.2, 6.5, 7.3, 7.6,
5.8, 6.8, 6.3, 5.8, 7.3, 8.4, 8.9, 7.7, 8.3, 8.1, 9, 7.9, 7.4, 8.3,
8.4, 5.5, 8, 7.7, 7.6, 6.7, 7.7, 6.6, 8.1, 7), PHYS = c(8.3, 8.5,
7.9, 8.8, 5.5, 8.6, 9.1, 6.8, 8.8, 8.5, 8.4, 6.9, 8.1, 6.2, 8.4,
8, 6.9, 8.1, 8, 7.2, 7.5, 7.4, 4.7, 7.8, 8.7, 9, 8.3, 8.8, 8.4,
8.9, 8.4, 8.1, 8.7, 8.8, 6.3, 8, 8.1, 8.5, 8, 8.1, 7.6, 8.3, 7.8),
RTEN = c(7.8, 8.7, 7.8, 8.7, 4.8, 8.6, 9, 5, 8.8, 7.9, 7.7, 7.2,
7.7, 6.5, 8, 7.6, 6.7, 7.4, 8, 6, 7.3, 6.6, 5.2, 7.6, 8.7, 9, 8.2,
8.7, 8.1, 9.2, 7.5, 7.9, 8.3, 8.8, 5.3, 8.2, 8, 7.7, 7, 7.9, 6.6,
8.1, 7.1), row.names = c("AARONSON,L.H.", "ALEXANDER,J.M.",
"ARMENTANO,A.J.", "BERDON,R.I.", "BRACKEN,J.J.", "BURNS,E.B.",
"CALLAHAN,R.J.", "COHEN,S.S.", "DALY,J.J.", "DANNEHY,J.F.",
"DEAN,H.H.", "DEVITA,H.J.", "DRISCOLL,P.J.", "GRILLO,A.E.",
"HADDEN,W.L.JR.", "HAMILL,E.C.", "HEALEY.A.H.", "HULL,T.C.",
"LEVINE,I.", "LEVISTER,R.L.", "MARTIN,L.F.", "MCGRATH,J.F.",
"MIGNONE,A.F.", "MISSAL,H.M.", "MULVEY,H.M.", "NARUK,H.J.",
"O\'BRIEN,F.J.", "O\'SULLIVAN,T.J.", "PASKEY,L.", "RUBINOW,J.E.",
"SADEN.G.A.", "SATANIELLO,A.G.", "SHEA,D.M.", "SHEA,J.F.JR.",
"SIDOR,W.J.", "SPEZIALE,J.A.", "SPONZO,M.J.", "STAPLETON,J.F.",
"TESTO,R.J.", "TIERNEY,W.L.JR.", "WALL,R.A.", "WRIGHT,D.B.",
"ZARRILLI,K.J."))
```

Tried using read.delim() and read.table() functions

```
US_judge_data<-read.table("US Judge Ratings.dat",header = TRUE,sep="\n")
```

I need a table with 12 variables namely CONT INTG DMNR ....
  and the total no of observations will be 43  the first row starting with AARONSON,L.H.", second with "ALEXANDER,J.M." and so on

Comment: Your .dat file contains the R code to produce the data set. Just copy and paste the data into R and run it or use source(filename.dat). It is already in a format that R understands. When you run the code, the name of the data frame will be USJudgeRatings.

Comment: Thanks a lot :).  I thought there's a way R can actually read this file and try getting the column names from there directly.

Comment: The `source` function executes the code in a file in the current environment. So running `source(file.dat)` is roughly the same as copy-pasting the contents of `file.dat` into the R console